# Create index error -The object name contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2

Tags: sql-server

I am getting the error while executing the following statement The object name 'servername.DatabaseName.Schema.TableName' contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2.

```
create nonclustered index idx_EstConsensusTemp1
    on [servername].[DatabaseName].[Schema].[TableName](FieldName)
```

Comment: Is it a linked server? Maybe try this https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic411412-149-1.aspx

Comment: Yes it is linked server

Comment: The link shared doesnt seem to be opening

Comment: I really wish sql server central would fix their site. Been a user there for years and lately it is just unusable. So much great information with so many great people. Quite frustrating.

Comment: Yeah the site seems to be really testy right now. Something like this: `EXECUTE ('USE Database';'Create index...')
AT LinkedServer`

Comment: Just dropped Steve at SSC an email about it.

Comment: Steve said they are having some hardware issues and should be standing up an additional web server soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the excellent link that Jacob referred to is down I was able to get the page to load but it is horribly slow.

Here is the answer from Grant Fritchey:

> Look up the EXECUTE statement in BOL:
>
> EXECUTE ('USE STUFF;DROP INDEX OWNER_idx ON dbo.OWNER') AT SQLnk
>
> The linked server has to support RPC calls:
>
> EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'SQLnk', @optname=N'rpc',
>   @optvalue=N'true'

Comment: I am creating this index within a storeprocedure. I am not sure if the stored procedure will allow execute statement

Comment: I have tried implementing it in the storedprocedure and it works.